# How to call a javascript function with an Eval argument on OnClientClick event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem with passing an argument to the client-side event OnClientClicking.

Whenever I pass an Eval argument, **there is a postback** for some reason, even though I wrote `"return false;"` in the `OnClientClick` code:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "toggleContactDetails("+Eval("ItemId")+"); return false;" %>'
```

I tried different things, including some solutions I found in similar questions.

I also tried this:

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("toggleContactDetails({0});return false;", Eval("ItemId"))%>'
```

or playing with the quotation marks; Nothing works.

I know the function isn't even running, since I wrote for testing:

```
function toggleContactDetails(itemId) {
    confirm(itemId);
}
```

In the javascript file, and no message appears.

Any advice, please?

Comment: OnClientClick='toggleContactDetails("+<%=Eval("ItemId")%>"); return false;" %>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in the question this sample:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "toggleContactDetails("+Eval("ItemId")+"); return false;" %>'
```

The problem with this is that it is rendered to the browser like this:

```
onclick="toggleContactDetails(Item Name 1); return false;"
```

This is broken `javascript` (missing quotes around `Item Name 1`)  so when you click the button, the `javascript` does not runt correctly, which means that `return false;` is not run. This in turn means that the `postback` will be triggered. In order for this to work you must render correct `javascript`:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "toggleContactDetails(\"" + Eval("ItemId") + "\"); return false;" %>'
```

Only relevant difference is `\"` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a value from the javascript function.

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return toggleContactDetails("+ Eval("ItemId")+ ");" %>'
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleContactDetails(itemId) {
        return confirm(itemId);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean it's a convention? I only used "confirm" in order to test whether the function is running (I guess alert would have been better) but the function I wanna use won't use confirm at all.

Comment: Ah, if you don't need a boolean returned from `confirm`, then the answer user1429080 provided does make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

i found this trick

```
OnClientClick='<%# JS("alert""" + Eval("item","")+""") %>'
```

and then in codebehind:

```
public static string JS(jsname)
{
    return string.Format("{0}", js);
}
```